# Cupcake Papers Peeling away

Tags: baking, cake, cupcakes

I've been making cupcakes for a long time with the same recipe and same brand of paper liners but recently my cupcake papers are pulling away from the baked cake shortly after they cool at room temperature.

Why is this happening now and what can I do to solve this? They just aren't as cute with the papers coming off the cake outwards.